# Junit basic test for native query not working properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to test in SpringBoot application using JUnit some query and I'm getting this error:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type DocumentRepositoryTest
```

```java
@Repository
public interface DocumentRepositoryTest extends DocumentRepository {

    @Query("SELECT * " +
            "FROM document d" +
            "WHERE d.id = :id")
    Object runQuery(@NonNull Integer id);
}

@SpringBootTest
public class DocumentServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    protected DocumentRepositoryTest documentRepositoryTest;

    @Test
    void testQuery() {
        Object o = documentRepositoryTest.runQuery(2);
    }
}
```

I cant understand why I have this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the DocumentRepository is being scanned by Spring component scanning. This can be done by adding the @ComponentScan annotation to your @SpringBootTest class.
Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.repository")
public class DocumentServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    protected DocumentRepositoryTest documentRepositoryTest;

    @Test
    void testQuery() {
        Object o = documentRepositoryTest.runQuery(2);
    }
}
```